# Unexpected results from XSLT (new user)

Tags: xml, xslt

Please help me understand why my first venture into XSLT transformation is not quite yielding the results I expect.

Here's my XML input:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="partition_table.xsl"?>

<pl version="01.00.0000">
    <de name="s_b" ins="3">
        <pa name="BT" type="bct">
            <ap> sec </ap>
            <ft> b2 </ft>
            <s> 32768 </s>
            <fsa> 0 </fsa>
            <aa> 8 </aa>
            <r> 0 </r>
        </pa>
        <pa name="m1" type="mb">
            <ap> sec </ap>
            <ft> b2 </ft>
            <s> 262144 </s>
            <fsa> 0 </fsa>
            <aa> 8 </aa>
            <r> 0 </r>
            <f> MBF </f>
        </pa>
        <pa name="m1b" type="mb">
            <ap> sec </ap>
            <ft> b2 </ft>
            <s> 262144 </s>
            <fsa> 0 </fsa>
            <aa> 8 </aa>
            <r> 0 </r>
            <f> MBF </f>
        </pa>
    </de>
</pl>
```

Here's my XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:strip-space elements="ap fst s fsa aa r f" />
<xsl:template match="/">|N|T|AP|FST|S|FSA|AA|R|F|
|:---|:---|:-----------|:------|---:|-----------:|--------------:|-------:|:-------|
  <xsl:for-each select="pl/de/pa">|<xsl:value-of select="@n"/>|<xsl:value-of select="@t"/>|<xsl:value-of select="ap"/>|<xsl:value-of select="fst"/>|<xsl:value-of select="s"/>|<xsl:value-of select="fsa"/>|<xsl:value-of select="aa"/>|<xsl:value-of select="r"/> %|<xsl:value-of select="f"/>|
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I get this output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>|N|T|AP|FST|S|FSA|AA|R|F|
|:---|:---|:-----------|:------|---:|-----------:|--------------:|-------:|:-------|
  ||| sec || 32768 | 0 | 8 | 0  %||
  ||| sec || 262144 | 0 | 8 | 0  %| MBF |
  ||| sec || 262144 | 0 | 8 | 0  %| MBF |
```

There are two problems. The first is the appearance of an `<?xml...?>` tag at the start of the output. It's not in the XSLT, and since I'm generating markdown I do not want it!

The second problem is that the `<xsl:strip-space.../>` tag is being ignored. I tried `elements="*"` but I got the same result.

I'm testing with the XSLT test tool at https://xslttest.appspot.com/.

Answer (score 0):

you should add these on your xslt

```
<xsl:output method="text" />
```

Here's your complete xslt code.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:strip-space elements="ap fst s fsa aa r f" />
    <xsl:template match="/">|N|T|AP|FST|S|FSA|AA|R|F|
|:---|:---|:-----------|:------|---:|-----------:|--------------:|-------:|:-------|
        <xsl:for-each select="pl/de/pa">|<xsl:value-of select="@n"/>|<xsl:value-of select="@t"/>|<xsl:value-of select="ap"/>|<xsl:value-of select="fst"/>|<xsl:value-of select="s"/>|<xsl:value-of select="fsa"/>|<xsl:value-of select="aa"/>|<xsl:value-of select="r"/> %|<xsl:value-of select="f"/>|
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

`<xsl:strip-space` only applies on nodes. visit this [site](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/xslt-2nd-edition/9780596527211/ch04s07s02.html)

I think what you need is

```
select="normalize-space(.)"
```

Comment: Actually, with `method="text"`, it is unnecessary to say `omit-xml-declaration="yes"` and `indent="no"`, since you will never get an XML declaration or indentation when generating plain text.